# onTouchEvent slide activate from only one direction swipe

Tags: java, android

I got this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    switch(event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            x1 = event.getX();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            x2 = event.getX();
            float deltaX = x2 - x1;
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }
            break;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

...And I should make the onTouchEvent activate/do the action only from:

- Left to Right swipe
- or Right to Left swipe

(Not both at the same time)

Comment: instead of doing all that low level `MotionEvent` stuff by yourself, better read about `GestureDetector`

Comment: find the solution thanks for advice